# How to copy entire data using row by row and paste to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy my data from one worksheet to another worksheet. I want to copy the first row and paste then copy the second row and then paste on the next empty row in the target sheet. Actually I want to copy data using row by row and in loop until the end of the row is reached in the data sheet. when the macro reach at the end of the row, and there is no data on the last row then it show pop up finish message.

I am trying following code but it is not fulfil my needs. Any suggest and help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
Sub InsertData()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long, lDestLastRow As Long

'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Warranty Template.xlsm").Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("QA Matrix Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Plant Sheet")

'1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
'Offset property moves down 1 row
lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row

'3. Copy & Paste Data
wsCopy.Range("A5:A" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("D" & lDestLastRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code should run as it is. Are you sure that both involved workbooks are open? Anyhow, in such a case, an error should be raised... What do you mea by "not fulfil my needs"? Try placing a break point on the line `wsCopy.Range("A5:A" & lCopyLastRow).Copy` and see what is shown when you move the cursor over the involved variables (`lCopyLastRow` and `lDestLastRow`). Are they what you think they should be?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is two ways of solving your task (see part 3)

```
Sub InsertData()

    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long, lDestLastRow As Long, row As Long

    'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Warranty Template.xlsm").Worksheets("PivotTable")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("QA Matrix Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Plant Sheet")

    '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
    'Offset property moves down 1 row
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count,4).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row

    '3. Copy & Paste Data
    For row = 5 To lCopyLastRow ' Cycle form 5th row (as well as you used range from A5) to last filled row (in A column)
        ' First: by copying data (not effective way, your solution is better)
        wsCopy.Range("A" & row).Copy wsDest.Range("D" & (lDestLastRow + (row - 5)))
        
        ' Second: by filling the data
        ' Like this: wsDest.Range("D" & (lDestLastRow + (row - 5))) = wsCopy.Range("A" & row)
    Next row

End Sub
```